# How can I deserialize tons of confusing .JSON to a listbox?

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I am working with Json.net to fill ListBox Items with a list of movies (Title, Year, and url to medium-image) from this really long and heavy json code:

```
{(...blabla)"movies":[{"id":4120,"url":"https:\/\/yts.to\/movie\/glee-2009","title":"Glee","year":2009,"medium_cover_image":"https:\/\/s.ynet.io\/assets\/images\/movies\/glee_2009\/medium-cover.jpg","state":"ok",}{(...blabla}
```

Problem is, I have just started working with Json.net and am really confused by what I have to do. I've just been going round and round with code samples I don't understand. Could I please get some C# Code for deserializing that data in here: `Article article1 = new Article() { Name = "MovieTitle", ImagePath = "URL", Year="0000" };`in a loop?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: I hope you don't expect anyone to read all that JSON.

Comment: @user2950509 - actually your edit makes it worse, your JSON is now invalid and can't be posted to http://json2csharp.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To deal with this:

1. Go to http://json2csharp.com/ and post your JSON there.
2. Copy the resulting classes to Visual Studio.
3. There's a named value in the JSON with the name `"@meta"`, which gets translated to the following invalid property name:

   ```
   public Meta __invalid_name__@meta { get; set; }
   ```

   Fix it as follows:

   ```
   [JsonProperty("@meta")]
   public Meta Metadata { get; set; }
   ```
4. Extract the desired data using Linq.

Thus:

```
public class Torrent
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string hash { get; set; }
    public string quality { get; set; }
    public int seeds { get; set; }
    public int peers { get; set; }
    public string size { get; set; }
    public long size_bytes { get; set; }
    public string date_uploaded { get; set; }
    public int date_uploaded_unix { get; set; }
}

public class Movie
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string imdb_code { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string title_long { get; set; }
    public string slug { get; set; }
    public int year { get; set; }
    public double rating { get; set; }
    public int runtime { get; set; }
    public List<string> genres { get; set; }
    public string language { get; set; }
    public string mpa_rating { get; set; }
    public string background_image { get; set; }
    public string small_cover_image { get; set; }
    public string medium_cover_image { get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }
    public List<Torrent> torrents { get; set; }
    public string date_uploaded { get; set; }
    public int date_uploaded_unix { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public int movie_count { get; set; }
    public int limit { get; set; }
    public int page_number { get; set; }
    public List<Movie> movies { get; set; }
}

public class Meta
{
    public int server_time { get; set; }
    public string server_timezone { get; set; }
    public int api_version { get; set; }
    public string execution_time { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string status_message { get; set; }
    public Data data { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("@meta")]
    public Meta Metadata { get; set; }
}
```

Then, given your class:

```
public class Article
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }
    public string Year { get; set; }
}
```

Use it like:

```
        var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
        var articles = root.data.movies.Select(m => new Article { Name = m.title, ImagePath = m.medium_cover_image, Year = m.year.ToString() }).ToList();

        Debug.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(articles, Formatting.Indented));
```

From which the debug output is:

> ```
> [
>   {
>     "Name": "Glee",
>     "ImagePath": "https://s.ynet.io/assets/images/movies/glee_2009/medium-cover.jpg",
>     "Year": "2009"
>   },
>   {
>     "Name": "Road Wars",
>     "ImagePath": "https://s.ynet.io/assets/images/movies/road_wars_2015/medium-cover.jpg",
>     "Year": "2015"
>   },
>   .... several omitted
> ]
> ```

Comment: Thank you tons, but I'm now facing another problem, I can't seem to figure out how to download then convert the .json data to a string? starting, from a simple url ("https://yts.to/api/v2/list_movies.json?limit=25&page=1). I know in Windows phone 8 I would use WebClient, but it seems that wp8.1 is only letting me use HttpClient...

Comment: @user2950509 - then you should ask another question.  The preferred format for questions is [one question per post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post).  I'm not a phone developer so somebody else likely would be able to provide a quicker answer.